# Store events from other programs

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I want to store events from other applications in my own app. Examples of events: when Word is opened, minimized or a file is opened.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Unless the other app exposes it, via whatever mechanism, you are shit out of luck.

Comment: @leppie: is the "shit out of luck" from the official MSDN documentation? :)

Comment: @alex: MSDN has a characteristic way of being obtuse when simpler phrasing might do.

Comment: As the comments say, the other app must expose them in any way. Do you open word by your app?

Comment: @Daniel: Well, the original post was rather lacking. But after the edit, the -1 should have been retracted, yes. An active community is a good community.

Comment: I think generally there is not way to do this! ... so ...can i access to open windows in other applications and their properties' form?

Comment: @amir: Hold on, some of the commenters here have no clue what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EventLog`.

You must set `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true`

And When an event add to specified event log the 
 `EntryWritten` event handler will raise

> It is the simplest way to handle os
>   events

sample code

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog s = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application", ".", "");
    s.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    s.EntryWritten += delegate(object st, System.Diagnostics.EntryWrittenEventArgs ew)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ew.Entry.Message);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Running a program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813609.aspx) and [opening a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813602.aspx) are OS events (they involve security checks), and can be captured using the Windows built-in auditing features.  Those are off-topic here, direct further questions to ServerFault.com

Minimizing a program is an example of an application message, to get those you would need to install a hook using `SetWindowsHookEx`.  Beginning in .NET 4 (which introduces parallel runtime support), this can be done with C#, but it's not recommended.  One huge issue you need to be aware of is that your event capture code must NEVER generate events of its own, or else you will start a chain reaction that crashes all running programs.

Comment: How is capturing and reacting to Audit events in code off topic here?

Comment: @C: OS configuration is off-topic here.  No programming is required to set audit policy.  Audit events are captured by Windows and stored in the event log.

Comment: @amir: For which part?  Auditing is provided by the OS, you don't need to write any code.  MSDN provides examples of `SetWindowsHookEx`.