# Retrieving System Logs in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, system, logging

Im wondering if there is a way to list the system logs in a listview, then when clicked, a textbox below lists the details of the specific log.

And can someone provide a quick sample of reading an event from the event log, in Winform, on Win7, with C#?

Comment: what OS, what framework? Winforms, Asp.net, silverlight or WPF? Can you provide som code of what you already achieved?

Comment: Stop wondering, it is possible.

Comment: Crap, sorry, Winforms on Win7. Mainly just wondering if C# already had a library or class for something like this before I started to know whether I would need to write one or if there was an existing one.

Answer (score 3):

go check this tutorial
it covers working with the system log
[System logs in c#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/93268-working-with-the-system-event-log-with-c#-intro/)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand ur question correctly I must tell u that u better to have a look at [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) page , I have answered a question [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5991192/726631) that I think may help u